# How to get List fonts on IOS 12?

Tags: ios12

How to get the list of fonts on IOS 12?

[iosfontlist.com](https://iosfontlist.com) has no information about ios 12.

I tried searching on Google but found no information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print them one by one:

```
for fontFamilyName in UIFont.familyNames {
    for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontFamilyName){
        print("Family: \(fontFamilyName)     Font: \(fontName)")
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
All fonts printed here:

> Family: Copperplate     Font: Copperplate-Light Family: Copperplate
>   Font: Copperplate Family: Copperplate     Font: Copperplate-Bold
>   Family: Apple SD Gothic Neo     Font: AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin Family:
>   Apple SD Gothic Neo     Font: AppleSDGothicNeo-Light Family: Apple SD
>   Gothic Neo     Font: AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular Family: Apple SD Gothic
>   Neo     Font: AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold Family: Apple SD Gothic Neo
>   Font: AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold Family: Apple SD Gothic Neo     Font:
>   AppleSDGothicNeo-UltraLight Family: Apple SD Gothic Neo     Font:
>   AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium Family: Thonburi     Font: Thonburi Family:
>   Thonburi     Font: Thonburi-Light Family: Thonburi     Font:
>   Thonburi-Bold Family: Gill Sans     Font: GillSans-Italic Family: Gill
>   Sans     Font: GillSans-SemiBold Family: Gill Sans     Font:
>   GillSans-UltraBold Family: Gill Sans     Font: GillSans-Light Family:
>   Gill Sans     Font: GillSans-Bold Family: Gill Sans     Font: GillSans
>   Family: Gill Sans     Font: GillSans-SemiBoldItalic Family: Gill Sans 
>   Font: GillSans-BoldItalic Family: Gill Sans     Font:
>   GillSans-LightItalic Family: Marker Felt     Font: MarkerFelt-Thin
>   Family: Marker Felt     Font: MarkerFelt-Wide Family: Hiragino Maru
>   Gothic ProN     Font: HiraMaruProN-W4 Family: Courier New     Font:
>   CourierNewPS-ItalicMT Family: Courier New     Font: CourierNewPSMT
>   Family: Courier New     Font: CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT Family:
>   Courier New     Font: CourierNewPS-BoldMT Family: Kohinoor Telugu
>   Font: KohinoorTelugu-Regular Family: Kohinoor Telugu     Font:
>   KohinoorTelugu-Medium Family: Kohinoor Telugu     Font:
>   KohinoorTelugu-Light Family: Avenir Next Condensed     Font:
>   AvenirNextCondensed-Heavy Family: Avenir Next Condensed     Font:
>   AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic Family: Avenir Next Condensed
>   Font: AvenirNextCondensed-Regular Family: Avenir Next Condensed
>   Font: AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLightItalic Family: Avenir Next
>   Condensed     Font: AvenirNextCondensed-Medium Family: Avenir Next
>   Condensed     Font: AvenirNextCondensed-HeavyItalic Family: Avenir
>   Next Condensed     Font: AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic Family:
>   Avenir Next Condensed     Font: AvenirNextCondensed-Bold Family:
>   Avenir Next Condensed     Font: AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold Family:
>   Avenir Next Condensed     Font: AvenirNextCondensed-BoldItalic Family:
>   Avenir Next Condensed     Font: AvenirNextCondensed-Italic Family:
>   Avenir Next Condensed     Font: AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLight Family:
>   Tamil Sangam MN     Font: TamilSangamMN Family: Tamil Sangam MN
>   Font: TamilSangamMN-Bold Family: Helvetica Neue     Font:
>   HelveticaNeue-UltraLightItalic Family: Helvetica Neue     Font:
>   HelveticaNeue-Medium Family: Helvetica Neue     Font:
>   HelveticaNeue-MediumItalic Family: Helvetica Neue     Font:
>   HelveticaNeue-UltraLight Family: Helvetica Neue     Font:
>   HelveticaNeue-Italic Family: Helvetica Neue     Font:
>   HelveticaNeue-Light Family: Helvetica Neue     Font:
>   HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic Family: Helvetica Neue     Font:
>   HelveticaNeue-LightItalic Family: Helvetica Neue     Font:
>   HelveticaNeue-Bold Family: Helvetica Neue     Font: HelveticaNeue-Thin
>   Family: Helvetica Neue     Font: HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack Family:
>   Helvetica Neue     Font: HelveticaNeue Family: Helvetica Neue
>   Font: HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold Family: Helvetica Neue     Font:
>   HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic Family: Gurmukhi MN     Font: GurmukhiMN-Bold
>   Family: Gurmukhi MN     Font: GurmukhiMN Family: Georgia     Font:
>   Georgia-BoldItalic Family: Georgia     Font: Georgia-Italic Family:
>   Georgia     Font: Georgia Family: Georgia     Font: Georgia-Bold
>   Family: Times New Roman     Font: TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT Family:
>   Times New Roman     Font: TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT Family: Times
>   New Roman     Font: TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT Family: Times New Roman
>   Font: TimesNewRomanPSMT Family: Sinhala Sangam MN     Font:
>   SinhalaSangamMN-Bold Family: Sinhala Sangam MN     Font:
>   SinhalaSangamMN Family: Arial Rounded MT Bold     Font:
>   ArialRoundedMTBold Family: Kailasa     Font: Kailasa-Bold Family:
>   Kailasa     Font: Kailasa Family: Kohinoor Devanagari     Font:
>   KohinoorDevanagari-Regular Family: Kohinoor Devanagari     Font:
>   KohinoorDevanagari-Light Family: Kohinoor Devanagari     Font:
>   KohinoorDevanagari-Semibold Family: Kohinoor Bangla     Font:
>   KohinoorBangla-Regular Family: Kohinoor Bangla     Font:
>   KohinoorBangla-Semibold Family: Kohinoor Bangla     Font:
>   KohinoorBangla-Light Family: Chalkboard SE     Font: ChalkboardSE-Bold
>   Family: Chalkboard SE     Font: ChalkboardSE-Light Family: Chalkboard
>   SE     Font: ChalkboardSE-Regular Family: Apple Color Emoji     Font:
>   AppleColorEmoji Family: PingFang TC     Font: PingFangTC-Regular
>   Family: PingFang TC     Font: PingFangTC-Thin Family: PingFang TC
>   Font: PingFangTC-Medium Family: PingFang TC     Font:
>   PingFangTC-Semibold Family: PingFang TC     Font: PingFangTC-Light
>   Family: PingFang TC     Font: PingFangTC-Ultralight Family: Gujarati
>   Sangam MN     Font: GujaratiSangamMN Family: Gujarati Sangam MN
>   Font: GujaratiSangamMN-Bold Family: Geeza Pro     Font: GeezaPro-Bold
>   Family: Geeza Pro     Font: GeezaPro Family: Damascus     Font:
>   DamascusBold Family: Damascus     Font: DamascusLight Family: Damascus
>   Font: Damascus Family: Damascus     Font: DamascusMedium Family:
>   Damascus     Font: DamascusSemiBold Family: Noteworthy     Font:
>   Noteworthy-Bold Family: Noteworthy     Font: Noteworthy-Light Family:
>   Avenir     Font: Avenir-Oblique Family: Avenir     Font:
>   Avenir-HeavyOblique Family: Avenir     Font: Avenir-Heavy Family:
>   Avenir     Font: Avenir-BlackOblique Family: Avenir     Font:
>   Avenir-BookOblique Family: Avenir     Font: Avenir-Roman Family:
>   Avenir     Font: Avenir-Medium Family: Avenir     Font: Avenir-Black
>   Family: Avenir     Font: Avenir-Light Family: Avenir     Font:
>   Avenir-MediumOblique Family: Avenir     Font: Avenir-Book Family:
>   Avenir     Font: Avenir-LightOblique Family: Mishafi     Font:
>   DiwanMishafi Family: Academy Engraved LET     Font:
>   AcademyEngravedLetPlain Family: Futura     Font:
>   Futura-CondensedExtraBold Family: Futura     Font: Futura-Medium
>   Family: Futura     Font: Futura-Bold Family: Futura     Font:
>   Futura-CondensedMedium Family: Futura     Font: Futura-MediumItalic
>   Family: Party LET     Font: PartyLetPlain Family: Kannada Sangam MN
>   Font: KannadaSangamMN-Bold Family: Kannada Sangam MN     Font:
>   KannadaSangamMN Family: Arial Hebrew     Font: ArialHebrew-Bold
>   Family: Arial Hebrew     Font: ArialHebrew-Light Family: Arial Hebrew 
>   Font: ArialHebrew Family: Farah     Font: Farah Family: Arial
>   Font: Arial-BoldMT Family: Arial     Font: Arial-BoldItalicMT Family:
>   Arial     Font: Arial-ItalicMT Family: Arial     Font: ArialMT Family:
>   Chalkduster     Font: Chalkduster Family: Kefa     Font: Kefa-Regular
>   Family: Hoefler Text     Font: HoeflerText-Italic Family: Hoefler Text
>   Font: HoeflerText-Black Family: Hoefler Text     Font:
>   HoeflerText-Regular Family: Hoefler Text     Font:
>   HoeflerText-BlackItalic Family: Optima     Font: Optima-ExtraBlack
>   Family: Optima     Font: Optima-BoldItalic Family: Optima     Font:
>   Optima-Italic Family: Optima     Font: Optima-Regular Family: Optima
>   Font: Optima-Bold Family: Palatino     Font: Palatino-Italic Family:
>   Palatino     Font: Palatino-Roman Family: Palatino     Font:
>   Palatino-BoldItalic Family: Palatino     Font: Palatino-Bold Family:
>   Malayalam Sangam MN     Font: MalayalamSangamMN-Bold Family: Malayalam
>   Sangam MN     Font: MalayalamSangamMN Family: Al Nile     Font: AlNile
>   Family: Al Nile     Font: AlNile-Bold Family: Lao Sangam MN     Font:
>   LaoSangamMN Family: Bradley Hand     Font: BradleyHandITCTT-Bold
>   Family: Hiragino Mincho ProN     Font: HiraMinProN-W3 Family: Hiragino
>   Mincho ProN     Font: HiraMinProN-W6 Family: PingFang HK     Font:
>   PingFangHK-Medium Family: PingFang HK     Font: PingFangHK-Thin
>   Family: PingFang HK     Font: PingFangHK-Regular Family: PingFang HK
>   Font: PingFangHK-Ultralight Family: PingFang HK     Font:
>   PingFangHK-Semibold Family: PingFang HK     Font: PingFangHK-Light
>   Family: Helvetica     Font: Helvetica-Oblique Family: Helvetica
>   Font: Helvetica-BoldOblique Family: Helvetica     Font: Helvetica
>   Family: Helvetica     Font: Helvetica-Light Family: Helvetica
>   Font: Helvetica-Bold Family: Helvetica     Font:
>   Helvetica-LightOblique Family: Courier     Font: Courier-BoldOblique
>   Family: Courier     Font: Courier-Oblique Family: Courier     Font:
>   Courier Family: Courier     Font: Courier-Bold Family: Cochin
>   Font: Cochin-Italic Family: Cochin     Font: Cochin-Bold Family:
>   Cochin     Font: Cochin Family: Cochin     Font: Cochin-BoldItalic
>   Family: Trebuchet MS     Font: TrebuchetMS-Bold Family: Trebuchet MS
>   Font: TrebuchetMS-Italic Family: Trebuchet MS     Font:
>   Trebuchet-BoldItalic Family: Trebuchet MS     Font: TrebuchetMS
>   Family: Devanagari Sangam MN     Font: DevanagariSangamMN Family:
>   Devanagari Sangam MN     Font: DevanagariSangamMN-Bold Family: Oriya
>   Sangam MN     Font: OriyaSangamMN Family: Oriya Sangam MN     Font:
>   OriyaSangamMN-Bold Family: Rockwell     Font: Rockwell-Italic Family:
>   Rockwell     Font: Rockwell-Regular Family: Rockwell     Font:
>   Rockwell-Bold Family: Rockwell     Font: Rockwell-BoldItalic Family:
>   Snell Roundhand     Font: SnellRoundhand Family: Snell Roundhand
>   Font: SnellRoundhand-Bold Family: Snell Roundhand     Font:
>   SnellRoundhand-Black Family: Zapf Dingbats     Font: ZapfDingbatsITC
>   Family: Bodoni 72     Font: BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-Bold Family: Bodoni 72 
>   Font: BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-BookIta Family: Bodoni 72     Font:
>   BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-Book Family: Verdana     Font: Verdana-Italic
>   Family: Verdana     Font: Verdana Family: Verdana     Font:
>   Verdana-Bold Family: Verdana     Font: Verdana-BoldItalic Family:
>   American Typewriter     Font: AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold Family:
>   American Typewriter     Font: AmericanTypewriter-Condensed Family:
>   American Typewriter     Font: AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight
>   Family: American Typewriter     Font: AmericanTypewriter Family:
>   American Typewriter     Font: AmericanTypewriter-Bold Family: American
>   Typewriter     Font: AmericanTypewriter-Semibold Family: American
>   Typewriter     Font: AmericanTypewriter-Light Family: Avenir Next
>   Font: AvenirNext-Medium Family: Avenir Next     Font:
>   AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic Family: Avenir Next     Font:
>   AvenirNext-DemiBold Family: Avenir Next     Font:
>   AvenirNext-HeavyItalic Family: Avenir Next     Font:
>   AvenirNext-Regular Family: Avenir Next     Font: AvenirNext-Italic
>   Family: Avenir Next     Font: AvenirNext-MediumItalic Family: Avenir
>   Next     Font: AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic Family: Avenir Next
>   Font: AvenirNext-BoldItalic Family: Avenir Next     Font:
>   AvenirNext-Heavy Family: Avenir Next     Font: AvenirNext-Bold Family:
>   Avenir Next     Font: AvenirNext-UltraLight Family: Baskerville
>   Font: Baskerville-SemiBoldItalic Family: Baskerville     Font:
>   Baskerville-SemiBold Family: Baskerville     Font:
>   Baskerville-BoldItalic Family: Baskerville     Font: Baskerville
>   Family: Baskerville     Font: Baskerville-Bold Family: Baskerville
>   Font: Baskerville-Italic Family: Khmer Sangam MN     Font:
>   KhmerSangamMN Family: Didot     Font: Didot-Bold Family: Didot
>   Font: Didot Family: Didot     Font: Didot-Italic Family: Savoye LET
>   Font: SavoyeLetPlain Family: Bodoni Ornaments     Font:
>   BodoniOrnamentsITCTT Family: Symbol     Font: Symbol Family: Charter
>   Font: Charter-BlackItalic Family: Charter     Font: Charter-Bold
>   Family: Charter     Font: Charter-Roman Family: Charter     Font:
>   Charter-Black Family: Charter     Font: Charter-BoldItalic Family:
>   Charter     Font: Charter-Italic Family: Menlo     Font:
>   Menlo-BoldItalic Family: Menlo     Font: Menlo-Bold Family: Menlo
>   Font: Menlo-Italic Family: Menlo     Font: Menlo-Regular Family: Noto
>   Nastaliq Urdu     Font: NotoNastaliqUrdu Family: Bodoni 72 Smallcaps
>   Font: BodoniSvtyTwoSCITCTT-Book Family: DIN Alternate     Font:
>   DINAlternate-Bold Family: Papyrus     Font: Papyrus-Condensed Family:
>   Papyrus     Font: Papyrus Family: Hiragino Sans     Font:
>   HiraginoSans-W3 Family: Hiragino Sans     Font: HiraginoSans-W6
>   Family: PingFang SC     Font: PingFangSC-Medium Family: PingFang SC
>   Font: PingFangSC-Semibold Family: PingFang SC     Font:
>   PingFangSC-Light Family: PingFang SC     Font: PingFangSC-Ultralight
>   Family: PingFang SC     Font: PingFangSC-Regular Family: PingFang SC
>   Font: PingFangSC-Thin Family: Myanmar Sangam MN     Font:
>   MyanmarSangamMN Family: Myanmar Sangam MN     Font:
>   MyanmarSangamMN-Bold Family: Noto Sans Chakma     Font:
>   NotoSansChakma-Regular Family: Zapfino     Font: Zapfino Family:
>   Bodoni 72 Oldstyle     Font: BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-BookIt Family:
>   Bodoni 72 Oldstyle     Font: BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-Book Family: Bodoni
>   72 Oldstyle     Font: BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-Bold Family: Euphemia UCAS 
>   Font: EuphemiaUCAS Family: Euphemia UCAS     Font: EuphemiaUCAS-Italic
>   Family: Euphemia UCAS     Font: EuphemiaUCAS-Bold Family: DIN
>   Condensed     Font: DINCondensed-Bold

Comment: I'm not an ios programmer,
can you list it

Comment: You can see in edited section. But to see them lined up properly open edit option in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Available fonts in App
func availableFontsInApp() {

    let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames

    for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
        print("------------------------------")
        print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
        let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName )
        print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
    }
}
```

Font Family Name = [Copperplate]
Font Names = [["Copperplate-Light", "Copperplate", "Copperplate-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Heiti SC]
Font Names = [[]]

Font Family Name = [Apple SD Gothic Neo]
Font Names = [["AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin", "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light", "AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular", "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", "AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold", "AppleSDGothicNeo-UltraLight", "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium"]]

Font Family Name = [Thonburi]
Font Names = [["Thonburi", "Thonburi-Light", "Thonburi-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Gill Sans]
Font Names = [["GillSans-Italic", "GillSans-SemiBold", "GillSans-UltraBold", "GillSans-Light", "GillSans-Bold", "GillSans", "GillSans-SemiBoldItalic", "GillSans-BoldItalic", "GillSans-LightItalic"]]

Font Family Name = [Marker Felt]
Font Names = [["MarkerFelt-Thin", "MarkerFelt-Wide"]]

Font Family Name = [Hiragino Maru Gothic ProN]
Font Names = [["HiraMaruProN-W4"]]

Font Family Name = [Courier New]
Font Names = [["CourierNewPS-ItalicMT", "CourierNewPSMT", "CourierNewPS-BoldItalicMT", "CourierNewPS-BoldMT"]]

Font Family Name = [Kohinoor Telugu]
Font Names = [["KohinoorTelugu-Regular", "KohinoorTelugu-Medium", "KohinoorTelugu-Light"]]

Font Family Name = [Heiti TC]
Font Names = [[]]

Font Family Name = [Avenir Next Condensed]
Font Names = [["AvenirNextCondensed-Heavy", "AvenirNextCondensed-MediumItalic", "AvenirNextCondensed-Regular", "AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLightItalic", "AvenirNextCondensed-Medium", "AvenirNextCondensed-HeavyItalic", "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBoldItalic", "AvenirNextCondensed-Bold", "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold", "AvenirNextCondensed-BoldItalic", "AvenirNextCondensed-Italic", "AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLight"]]

Font Family Name = [Tamil Sangam MN]
Font Names = [["TamilSangamMN", "TamilSangamMN-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Helvetica Neue]
Font Names = [["HelveticaNeue-UltraLightItalic", "HelveticaNeue-Medium", "HelveticaNeue-MediumItalic", "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", "HelveticaNeue-Italic", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic", "HelveticaNeue-LightItalic", "HelveticaNeue-Bold", "HelveticaNeue-Thin", "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", "HelveticaNeue", "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold", "HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic"]]

Font Family Name = [Gurmukhi MN]
Font Names = [["GurmukhiMN-Bold", "GurmukhiMN"]]

Font Family Name = [Georgia]
Font Names = [["Georgia-BoldItalic", "Georgia-Italic", "Georgia", "Georgia-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Times New Roman]
Font Names = [["TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT", "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT", "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT", "TimesNewRomanPSMT"]]

Font Family Name = [Sinhala Sangam MN]
Font Names = [["SinhalaSangamMN-Bold", "SinhalaSangamMN"]]

Font Family Name = [Arial Rounded MT Bold]
Font Names = [["ArialRoundedMTBold"]]

Font Family Name = [Kailasa]
Font Names = [["Kailasa-Bold", "Kailasa"]]

Font Family Name = [Kohinoor Devanagari]
Font Names = [["KohinoorDevanagari-Regular", "KohinoorDevanagari-Light", "KohinoorDevanagari-Semibold"]]

Font Family Name = [Kohinoor Bangla]
Font Names = [["KohinoorBangla-Regular", "KohinoorBangla-Semibold", "KohinoorBangla-Light"]]

Font Family Name = [Chalkboard SE]
Font Names = [["ChalkboardSE-Bold", "ChalkboardSE-Light", "ChalkboardSE-Regular"]]

Font Family Name = [Apple Color Emoji]
Font Names = [["AppleColorEmoji"]]

Font Family Name = [PingFang TC]
Font Names = [["PingFangTC-Regular", "PingFangTC-Thin", "PingFangTC-Medium", "PingFangTC-Semibold", "PingFangTC-Light", "PingFangTC-Ultralight"]]

Font Family Name = [Gujarati Sangam MN]
Font Names = [["GujaratiSangamMN", "GujaratiSangamMN-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Geeza Pro]
Font Names = [["GeezaPro-Bold", "GeezaPro"]]

Font Family Name = [Damascus]
Font Names = [["DamascusBold", "DamascusLight", "Damascus", "DamascusMedium", "DamascusSemiBold"]]

Font Family Name = [Noteworthy]
Font Names = [["Noteworthy-Bold", "Noteworthy-Light"]]

Font Family Name = [Avenir]
Font Names = [["Avenir-Oblique", "Avenir-HeavyOblique", "Avenir-Heavy", "Avenir-BlackOblique", "Avenir-BookOblique", "Avenir-Roman", "Avenir-Medium", "Avenir-Black", "Avenir-Light", "Avenir-MediumOblique", "Avenir-Book", "Avenir-LightOblique"]]

Font Family Name = [Mishafi]
Font Names = [["DiwanMishafi"]]

Font Family Name = [Academy Engraved LET]
Font Names = [["AcademyEngravedLetPlain"]]

Font Family Name = [Futura]
Font Names = [["Futura-CondensedExtraBold", "Futura-Medium", "Futura-Bold", "Futura-CondensedMedium", "Futura-MediumItalic"]]

Font Family Name = [Party LET]
Font Names = [["PartyLetPlain"]]

Font Family Name = [Kannada Sangam MN]
Font Names = [["KannadaSangamMN-Bold", "KannadaSangamMN"]]

Font Family Name = [Arial Hebrew]
Font Names = [["ArialHebrew-Bold", "ArialHebrew-Light", "ArialHebrew"]]

Font Family Name = [Farah]
Font Names = [["Farah"]]

Font Family Name = [Arial]
Font Names = [["Arial-BoldMT", "Arial-BoldItalicMT", "Arial-ItalicMT", "ArialMT"]]

Font Family Name = [Chalkduster]
Font Names = [["Chalkduster"]]

Font Family Name = [Kefa]
Font Names = [["Kefa-Regular"]]

Font Family Name = [Hoefler Text]
Font Names = [["HoeflerText-Italic", "HoeflerText-Black", "HoeflerText-Regular", "HoeflerText-BlackItalic"]]

Font Family Name = [Optima]
Font Names = [["Optima-ExtraBlack", "Optima-BoldItalic", "Optima-Italic", "Optima-Regular", "Optima-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Palatino]
Font Names = [["Palatino-Italic", "Palatino-Roman", "Palatino-BoldItalic", "Palatino-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Malayalam Sangam MN]
Font Names = [["MalayalamSangamMN-Bold", "MalayalamSangamMN"]]

Font Family Name = [Al Nile]
Font Names = [["AlNile", "AlNile-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Lao Sangam MN]
Font Names = [["LaoSangamMN"]]

Font Family Name = [Bradley Hand]
Font Names = [["BradleyHandITCTT-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Hiragino Mincho ProN]
Font Names = [["HiraMinProN-W3", "HiraMinProN-W6"]]

Font Family Name = [PingFang HK]
Font Names = [["PingFangHK-Medium", "PingFangHK-Thin", "PingFangHK-Regular", "PingFangHK-Ultralight", "PingFangHK-Semibold", "PingFangHK-Light"]]

Font Family Name = [Helvetica]
Font Names = [["Helvetica-Oblique", "Helvetica-BoldOblique", "Helvetica", "Helvetica-Light", "Helvetica-Bold", "Helvetica-LightOblique"]]

Font Family Name = [Courier]
Font Names = [["Courier-BoldOblique", "Courier-Oblique", "Courier", "Courier-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Cochin]
Font Names = [["Cochin-Italic", "Cochin-Bold", "Cochin", "Cochin-BoldItalic"]]

Font Family Name = [Trebuchet MS]
Font Names = [["TrebuchetMS-Bold", "TrebuchetMS-Italic", "Trebuchet-BoldItalic", "TrebuchetMS"]]

Font Family Name = [Devanagari Sangam MN]
Font Names = [["DevanagariSangamMN", "DevanagariSangamMN-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Oriya Sangam MN]
Font Names = [["OriyaSangamMN", "OriyaSangamMN-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Rockwell]
Font Names = [["Rockwell-Italic", "Rockwell-Regular", "Rockwell-Bold", "Rockwell-BoldItalic"]]

Font Family Name = [Snell Roundhand]
Font Names = [["SnellRoundhand", "SnellRoundhand-Bold", "SnellRoundhand-Black"]]

Font Family Name = [Zapf Dingbats]
Font Names = [["ZapfDingbatsITC"]]

Font Family Name = [Bodoni 72]
Font Names = [["BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-Bold", "BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-BookIta", "BodoniSvtyTwoITCTT-Book"]]

Font Family Name = [Verdana]
Font Names = [["Verdana-Italic", "Verdana", "Verdana-Bold", "Verdana-BoldItalic"]]

Font Family Name = [American Typewriter]
Font Names = [["AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold", "AmericanTypewriter-Condensed", "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight", "AmericanTypewriter", "AmericanTypewriter-Bold", "AmericanTypewriter-Semibold", "AmericanTypewriter-Light"]]

Font Family Name = [Avenir Next]
Font Names = [["AvenirNext-Medium", "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic", "AvenirNext-DemiBold", "AvenirNext-HeavyItalic", "AvenirNext-Regular", "AvenirNext-Italic", "AvenirNext-MediumItalic", "AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic", "AvenirNext-BoldItalic", "AvenirNext-Heavy", "AvenirNext-Bold", "AvenirNext-UltraLight"]]

Font Family Name = [Baskerville]
Font Names = [["Baskerville-SemiBoldItalic", "Baskerville-SemiBold", "Baskerville-BoldItalic", "Baskerville", "Baskerville-Bold", "Baskerville-Italic"]]

Font Family Name = [Khmer Sangam MN]
Font Names = [["KhmerSangamMN"]]

Font Family Name = [Didot]
Font Names = [["Didot-Bold", "Didot", "Didot-Italic"]]

Font Family Name = [Savoye LET]
Font Names = [["SavoyeLetPlain"]]

Font Family Name = [Bodoni Ornaments]
Font Names = [["BodoniOrnamentsITCTT"]]

Font Family Name = [Symbol]
Font Names = [["Symbol"]]

Font Family Name = [Charter]
Font Names = [["Charter-BlackItalic", "Charter-Bold", "Charter-Roman", "Charter-Black", "Charter-BoldItalic", "Charter-Italic"]]

Font Family Name = [Menlo]
Font Names = [["Menlo-BoldItalic", "Menlo-Bold", "Menlo-Italic", "Menlo-Regular"]]

Font Family Name = [Noto Nastaliq Urdu]
Font Names = [["NotoNastaliqUrdu"]]

Font Family Name = [Bodoni 72 Smallcaps]
Font Names = [["BodoniSvtyTwoSCITCTT-Book"]]

Font Family Name = [DIN Alternate]
Font Names = [["DINAlternate-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Papyrus]
Font Names = [["Papyrus-Condensed", "Papyrus"]]

Font Family Name = [Hiragino Sans]
Font Names = [["HiraginoSans-W3", "HiraginoSans-W6"]]

Font Family Name = [PingFang SC]
Font Names = [["PingFangSC-Medium", "PingFangSC-Semibold", "PingFangSC-Light", "PingFangSC-Ultralight", "PingFangSC-Regular", "PingFangSC-Thin"]]

Font Family Name = [Zawgyi-One]
Font Names = [["Zawgyi-One"]]

Font Family Name = [Noto Sans Chakma]
Font Names = [["NotoSansChakma-Regular"]]

Font Family Name = [Myanmar Sangam MN]
Font Names = [["MyanmarSangamMN", "MyanmarSangamMN-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Zapfino]
Font Names = [["Zapfino"]]

Font Family Name = [Telugu Sangam MN]
Font Names = [[]]

Font Family Name = [Bodoni 72 Oldstyle]
Font Names = [["BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-BookIt", "BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-Book", "BodoniSvtyTwoOSITCTT-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Euphemia UCAS]
Font Names = [["EuphemiaUCAS", "EuphemiaUCAS-Italic", "EuphemiaUCAS-Bold"]]

Font Family Name = [Bangla Sangam MN]
Font Names = [[]]

Font Family Name = [DIN Condensed]
Font Names = [["DINCondensed-Bold"]]

**Storyboard**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not an ios programmer,
can you list it